# Need help finding a local RSS aggregator that will output a single feed

Tags: sharepoint, download, localhost, rss, aggregation

I'm trying to find an RSS feed aggregator that I can run locally or something. Basically, the problem is that I have multiple feeds coming from a private source for an intranet (SharePoint) site.

The feeds are not public and we needed to whitelist a lot of addresses just to get each one to show up. Unfortunately, the provider cannot combine these feeds into a single one for us to use and since they are private. Since these had to be white listed for local use only, I cannot use external resources such as http://www.rssmix.com/.

I've been looking for 3 days to find a solution to this, including building my own in PHP, which doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions on this would be helpful.

Thanks